# Why are my embedded hasMany relationships undefined?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm loading App.Structure objects using ember-data's fixtures adapter. These objects have embedded App.Overlay objects as a `hasMany` relationship, like this:

```
App.Structure = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  // hash of overlay paths
  overlays: DS.hasMany('App.Overlay', { embedded: true }),
});

App.Overlay = DS.Model.extend({
  view: DS.attr('string'),
  path: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Overlay.FIXTURES = [];

App.Structure.FIXTURES = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Test Structure",
  "overlays": [{
    "view": "Isometric",
    "path": "[elided to save space]"
  }],
}];
```

(Note that the empty fixtures array is to fix [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12112279/306084).)

Now I can load the `App.Structure`, but I can't get anything out of it. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/hA6VH/); the Structure can be accessed, and it's able to iterate over the `overlays` array, but the object(s) in the array are hollow shells with nothing in them.

Here's a console session picking at this:

```
> currStructure = App.fixtureStore.findAll(App.Structure).get('firstObject');
Class
> currStructure.get('name');
"Test Structure"
> currStructure.get('overlays').get('length');
1
> var overlay = currStructure.get('overlays').get('firstObject');
undefined
> overlay instanceof App.Overlay;
true
> overlay.get('view');
null
> overlay.get('path');
null
```

Why is this not working?

ETA: following @Kristaps' response, I've updated the fiddle. Now the first Overlay is still just a hollow shell, but any subsequent overlays aren't. Huh?

Comment: I'm having similar issues with a different controller, where e.g. App.Filter hasMany App.Structure, and for any given App.Filter instance, the 'structures' property has the correct number of elements of the correct type, but they're all empty (all attributes undefined).

Comment: This issue is blocking progress on two key parts of my app, and I'd really like to figure out either how to fix it or how to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because you are not setting structure_id in overlay object and belongsTo relationship in Overlay object. See fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/REtNV/

```
App.Structure = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    overlays: DS.hasMany('App.Overlay', {embedded: true})
});

App.Overlay = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    vi: DS.attr('string'),
    pa: DS.attr('string'),
    structure: DS.belongsTo('App.Structure'),    
});
```

and fixtures:

```
App.Overlay.FIXTURES = [];

App.Structure.FIXTURES = [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test Structure 0",
    "overlays": [{
        "id": 0,
        "structure_id": 0,
        "vi": "Overlay view 0.0",
        "pa": "Overlay path 0.0"},
    {
        "id": 1,
        "structure_id": 0,
        "vi": "Overlay view 0.1",
        "pa": "Overlay path 0.1"},
    {
        "id": 2,
        "structure_id": 0,                    
        "vi": "Overlay view 0.2",
        "pa": "Overlay path 0.2"}
                        ]},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Structure 1",
    "overlays": [{
        "id": 3,        
        "structure_id": 1,
        "vi": "Overlay view 1.0",
        "pa": "Overlay path 1.0"},
    {
        "id": 4,
        "structure_id": 0,
        "vi": "Overlay view 1.1",
        "pa": "Overlay path 1.1"},
    {
        "id": 5,
        "structure_id": 0,                    
        "vi": "Overlay view 1.2",
        "pa": "Overlay path 1.2"}
                        ]},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test Structure 2"}
];
```

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. Why, in the fiddle, are you using model functions (e.g. Overlay.p) to get attributes? Does that solve something I'm not aware of?

Comment: in emberjs 1pre apparently `view` and `path` are some sort of keywords because when i used them containing view class name was rendered. That was something that made me wondering for some time :).

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if my ambiguous use of the words `view` and `path` is the real issue. I hadn't thought of that. The model is intended to contain SVG "path" strings, indexed by the way the object is displayed (i.e. the view).

Comment: Nope, ambiguous `view` and `path` don't seem to be the entire issue.

Comment: Following your example I'm part-way there, but for some reason my fiddle still doesn't work quite like yours.

Comment: It's the same fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/pjmorse/hA6VH/ , with the base updated, so the new version has the same URL.

Comment: With two Overlays, the second one is displayed properly, but the first is empty as before.

Comment: i have no clue why, but if you change overlay_id from 0 to 1, it works
http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/hA6VH/36/

Comment: I tried changing the IDs to strings (e.g. "overlay-00" and "overlay-01" and that worked too. Maybe an ID of 0 looks too much like an ID of `null` to Javascript. I'm going to move this out of the fiddle and into the app now...

Comment: Well, that fixed *one* of my two issues, but the second one is still returning empty objects. Sometime this weekend I'll try to generate a fiddle for that one.

Comment: The second problem was that I'd forgotten I [can't camel-case attributes in the fixtures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11470545/306084).